# Change the border color for button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the border of the button if I click once on it and change back if I click again on it. (only if I click on it) Because I have 16 button in same class.So I want to make it possible to click in five from them in same time or all, etc...

HTML

```
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('M16.1')" class="pool" id="M16.1">M16.1</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('M16.2')" class="pool" id="M16.2">M16.2</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('M17')" class="pool" id="M17">M17</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('MR17')" class="pool" id="MR17">MR17</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('MSS16c')" class="pool" id="MSS16c">MSS16c</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('MSS17')" class="pool" id="MSS17">MSS17</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('MSS17c')" class="pool" id="MSS17c">MSS17c</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T15.0')" class="pool" id="T15.0">T15.0</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T15.0c')" class="pool" id="T15.0c">T15.0c</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T15.5')" class="pool" id="T15.5">T15.5</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T15.5c')" class="pool" id="T15.5c">T15.5c</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T15.8')" class="pool" id="T15.8">T15.8</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T15.8c')" class="pool" id="T15.8c">T15.8c</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T16.2')" class="pool" id="T16.2">T16.2</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T16.2c')" class="pool" id="T16.2c">T16.2c</button>
<button onclick="TogglePkgGroups('T16.5')" class="pool" id="T16.5">T16.5</button>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click & http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass

Comment: I doubt these are valid _`identifiers`_

Comment: `toggleClass` in order to achieve this and that class contains `border: 1px solid #color;` where you replace #color with color code required. Have a look at Jquery API docs

Comment: @Rayon if the OP is using HTML5 then they're valid. The only restrictions on an `id` in HTML5 is that it must be at least 1 character in length and contain no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="pool" id="M16.1">M16.1</button>
<button class="pool" id="M16.2">M16.2</button>
<button class="pool" id="M17">M17</button>
<button class="pool" id="MR17">MR17</button>
<button class="pool" id="MSS16c">MSS16c</button>
<button class="pool" id="MSS17">MSS17</button>
<button class="pool" id="MSS17c">MSS17c</button>
<button class="pool" id="T15.0">T15.0</button>
<button class="pool" id="T15.0c">T15.0c</button>
<button class="pool" id="T15.5">T15.5</button>
<button class="pool" id="T15.5c">T15.5c</button>
<button class="pool" id="T15.8">T15.8</button>
<button class="pool" id="T15.8c">T15.8c</button>
<button class="pool" id="T16.2">T16.2</button>
<button class="pool" id="T16.2c">T16.2c</button>
<button class="pool" id="T16.5">T16.5</button>
```

script:

```
$(function(){
 $(this).click(function(){
   $($this).toogleClass('select-pool');
 });
});
```

and css for `select-pool`:

```
.select-pool{
  border-color: red/*chabge it according your color*/
}
```